# SparkR and dplyr: window function count() using gapply

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I'm trying to implement simple query on Spark using "gapply", but face troubles.

This code works well.

```
library(SparkR)
library(dplyr)
df <- createDataFrame(iris)
createOrReplaceTempView(df, "iris")
display(SparkR::sql("SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Species) AS RowCount FROM iris"))
```

But I can't realize it via **gapply**

```
display(df %>% SparkR::group_by(df$Species) 
           %>% gapply(function(key, x) { y <- data.frame(x, SparkR::count()) }, 
               "Sepal_Length double, Sepal_Width double, Petal_Length double, Petal_Width double, Species string, RowCount integer"))
```

returns error

> SparkException: R unexpectedly exited. Caused by: EOFException:
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 235.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 235.0 (TID 374) (10.150.202.5 executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R unexpectedly exited. R worker
> produced errors: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘count’ for signature
> ‘"missing"’ Calls: compute ... computeFunc -> data.frame ->
>  ->  Execution halted

Is it possible to implement the window function "count" with **gapply** using pipes from **dplyr**?

Answer (score 1):

Just a small mistake, you should have used `base::nrow` function instead of `SparkR::count` inside `gapply`.

```
display(df %>% SparkR::group_by(df$Species) 
           %>% gapply(function(key, x) { y <- data.frame(x, nrow(x)) }, 
               "Sepal_Length double, Sepal_Width double, Petal_Length double, Petal_Width double, Species string, RowCount integer"))
```

This is how you could have done it through SparkR APIs using the `SparkR::windowPartitionBy` function, there is no need of creating any UDF here -

```
(
  df %>%
  SparkR::select(
    c(
      SparkR::columns(df),
      SparkR::over(
        SparkR::count(SparkR::lit(1)), 
        SparkR::windowPartitionBy(SparkR::column("Species"))
      ) %>% SparkR::alias("RowCount")
    )
  ) %>%
  display()
)
```